# IntelliJ maven dependency override icon is missing

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3

I noticed a small thing/issue some time ago with IntelliJ:

Usually when I create a project, I have a parent which defines the different modules and those modules inherit the dependencies from the parent.
When a dependency is overwritten by a child project, then on the left hand side IntelliJ displays a small icon and clicking on that it brings me to the dependency which gets overwritten.

To visualize what I am talking about:
[image]
I also created a very basic project to demonstrate this. It's available [here](https://github.com/tozo/intellij-maven-multi-module). Once it's imported you can see this icon.

Now some time ago I started working on a multi module Spring boot project and wanted to see what's the recommended way of creating one.

I found [this example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)

When you download it and import into IntelliJ, then that icon will not get displayed there.

I realize the project structure is a little bit different, but I would have thought that it should still be displayed. I know it's a very small problem, but still would be nice to see what's overwritten, so I don't have to define version number, etc.. for that dependency.

Is that the expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Software versions:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 (Ultimate Edition)
- Build #IU-182.3684.101, built on July 24, 2018
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows 7 6.1
- Maven 3.5.4

Comment: Override icon shows when parent pom has `dependencyManagement` section with the dependency with the same coordinates defined. Could be that the parent pom.xml can not be found or the dependency is not defined there?

Comment: @Andrey You are correct, the icon shows when the dependency is mentioned in the dependencyManagement, but the same spring-boot-starter-parent parent is used in both cases. Only difference (that I can see) is that in my example it's referenced from the root project, while in the spring boot example it's in a sub module. Probably this way IntelliJ can't recognize this hierarchy. I might raise this with them.