# What is this O symbol in POM.xml in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, pom.xml

I am having this `O` symbol in `IntelliJ` while editing `pom.xml`

When I click this `O` , it takes me to parent `pom.xml`
[image]

Please help me understand what is this and how to resolve it.

Comment: this means the <dependency></dependency> can be minimised

Comment: In case of using super pom you are able to see that. In multi module project or dependency management you are able to see that . check `dependencymanagement` or `bom` type or `multi module` maven project. Same as `OOP` parent child relationship .

Comment: its overrides somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This symbol is the "dependency has been overridden" symbol, and clicking it should navigate to the `pom.xml` containing the overridden dependency.

I cannot find a official source, but in this SO thread it is mentioned (albeit from an older version of IntelliJ):
[IntelliJ maven dependency override icon is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620108/intellij-maven-dependency-override-icon-is-missing)

In other words, you're overriding a dependency declared in the file the icon navigates to.